# Interface implemented in Service not working?

Tags: angular

I have a theme where there is interface  Resolve is implementing in service file which is working fine. I am doing the same method but the interface is not working. I mean when I initialize it in the ts file I need the products array from service which have data in array from the api I am using to get all the companies.

Here is my ts code:

```
export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {
      dataSource: FilesDataSource | null;
      displayedColumns = ['id',  'name'];
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    companyData: any;
    subscription: Subscription;
    imageUrl = environment.imageUrl;

      constructor(private companyService:CompanyService,private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new FilesDataSource(this.companyService, this.paginator, this.sort);
        fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
            debounceTime(150),
            distinctUntilChanged()
        ).subscribe(() => {
            if ( !this.dataSource )
            {
                return;
            }
            this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
        });

      }

    export class FilesDataSource extends DataSource<any>
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the CompanyService

```
@Injectable()
    export class CompanyService implements Resolve<any>
    {
         baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
       token: string; 
        products: any[];
        onProductsChanged: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});

        constructor(
            private http: HttpClient,
            private authService: AuthService
        )

        {
        }

        /**
         * Resolve
         * @param {ActivatedRouteSnapshot} route
         * @param {RouterStateSnapshot} state
         * @returns {Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any}
         */
        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any
        {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                Promise.all([
                    this.getProducts()
                ]).then(

                    () => {
                        resolve();
                    },
                    reject
                );
            });
        }

        getProducts(): Promise<any>
        {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const token = this.authService.getToken();
                this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'companies?access-token='+token)
                    .subscribe((response: any) => {
                        this.products = response;
                        console.log(this.products);
                        this.onProductsChanged.next(this.products);
                        resolve(response);
                    }, reject);
            });
        }
    }
```

Here the resolve mehtod implemented in the CompanyService is not working when I initialize it in the company ts constructor.The same method is working fine in the local theme demo. I don't know what I'm missing in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have done it my self. I dont know how it pass the data. the thing i am missing is i have to add it in routing like this**

```
 {
        path     : 'company',
        component: CompanyComponent,
        resolve  : {
          data: CompanyService
      }
    },
```